# How to load a bean only if a property is false or not defined?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean, spring-properties

I've a bean that should be loaded only if a property is false or not defined. If I annotate it with:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "myFeature1", name = "enable", havingValue = "false")
```

the property `myFeature1.enable` has to be explicitly set to `false`. This property is defined as a boolean with a false default value in a [`@ConfigurationProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html) annotated class, but this annotation seems to be treated too late in the application startup so the `myFeature1.enable` property has to be used as a string from the [`Environment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html).

I try to add the annotation:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "dlcm.module.auth", name = "enable", matchIfMissing = true)
```

but [`@ConditionalOnProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) is not a repeatable annotation.

I've also tried to use a [`@ConditionalOnExpression`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnExpression.html)

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${dlcm.module.auth.enable}' == 'false' or '${dlcm.module.auth.enable}' == ''")
```

but the property placeholder seems to be replaced by something else than the empty string.

So my question is: How to load a bean only if a property is false or not defined?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to use a [`@ConditionalOnExpression`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnExpression.html) annotation with a default value in the property placeholder:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${dlcm.module.auth.enable:false}' == 'false'")
```